# How better import excel file to react app?

Tags: reactjs

I understand how export data from react app and download it loke excel but how import data from exel to react app, into table?
Maybe some good library exist?

Comment: when i search for libraries i look at the number of dependencies and size (just use google with `npm` + `react` keywords) https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ramonak/react-excel

Answer (score 0):

If made a great experience with the 'xlsx' npm library.

Please remember to avoid reading empty lines/ rows with the option: blankrows.

Example line: xlsx.utils.sheet_to_json(ws, {header:1, blankrows: false, defval: '' });